# Why the dagger graph works works in java but in Kotlin it says missing Provides when I have provided?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have some issues when converting dagger interfaces from java to Kotlin

I got [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Here is my interface

```
   interface TopicConfigModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey(NAME)
    fun bindCommandHandler(handler: TopicCommandHandler): CommandHandler

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @FragmentScope
        fun provideHubsConfig(
            commandRegistry: Map<String, CommandHandler>
        ): Config {
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

and CommandHandler is java interface

````
public interface HubsCommandHandler {```}
````

Comment: try to use `commandRegistry: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards CommandHandler>`, also you don't need `@JvmStatic` (I assume that you're using dagger 2.26 or higher)

Comment: @IR42 It works  but I,  am not sure why we need JvmSuppressWildcards .
And please write down as answer I will vote for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map` in Kotlin is covariant ([variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance)) on its value type (`public interface Map<K, out V>`), but `Map` in Java is not. Your function will be translated to

```
Config provideHubsConfig(Map<String, ? extends CommandHandler> commandRegistry) { ... }
```

but dagger provides exactly `Map<String, CommandHandler>`. So we need to suppress wildcards with `@JvmSuppressWildcards`

```
commandRegistry: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards CommandHandler>
```

[Calling Kotlin from Java - variant-generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics)